# Count the number of Purchase Orders that occur within a Range

Tags: sql, count, sum

I have one table (order_lines) that contains (order_lines_order_header_id) which is the PO Number and I have (order_lines.accounting_total) which is the value of the specific PO line.

I need to group the sum of each 'order_header_id' into four ranges. The first range is Purchase Orders under $500. The second is Purchase Orders between $501 and $1000. The third range between $1001 and $10,000. The forth is all POs over $10,000.

I need the results to look like this:

```
Count of POs under $500 -- ####
Count of POs over $501 Under $1000-- ####
Count of POs over $1,001 Under $10,000 --####
Count of POs over $10,000-- ####
```

Here's what I have so far but it's not working:

```
SELECT COUNT(order_lines.order_header_id) where SUM(order_lines.accounting_total) <= 500 as Orders_Under_500
From order_lines
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need  a subquery to calculate the total amount per order.  Then you need another query to get the counts you are looking for:

```
select (case when total < 500 then 'Less than $500'
             when total < 1000 then 'Between $500 and $1,000'
             when total < 10000 then 'Between $1,000 and $10,000'
             else 'Over $10,000'
        end) as grp,
       count(*) as Numorders
from (select ol.order_header_id, sum(accounting_total) as total
      from order_lines ol
      group by ol.order_header_id
     ) ol
group by (case when total < 500 then 'Less than $500'
               when total < 1000 then 'Between $500 and $1,000'
               when total < 10000 then 'Between $1,000 and $10,000'
               else 'Over $10,000'
          end);
```

Comment: If I wanted to add another column for the Total Value of all the POs in that range- do I need to repeat Everything from "From" down? and just create a SUM of ol.Accoutning_Total?

Comment: @BenSimmons . . . You would just add `SUM(AccountingTotal)` as another column.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not in order, the correct form would be:

```
SELECT COUNT(order_header_id) 
FROM order_lines 
WHERE SUM(accounting_total) <= 500
```

However, a different query is needed to select all that you need in one query:

```
SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN accounting_total <500 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `500`,
SUM(CASE WHEN accounting_total BETWEEN 500 AND 1000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `500-1000`
SUM(CASE WHEN accounting_total BETWEEN 1000 AND 10000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `1000-10000`
SUM(CASE WHEN accounting_total >10000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `10000`
FROM order_lines
```

Alternatively (not tested):

```
SELECT COUNT(order_header_id) 
FROM order_lines 
WHERE SUM(accounting_total) <= 500 
OR (SUM(accounting_total) > 500 AND SUM(accounting_total) <= 1000 )
OR (SUM(accounting_total) > 1000 AND SUM(accounting_total) <= 10000 )
OR SUM(accounting_total) > 10000
GROUP BY  COUNT(order_header_id)
```

Hope that helped.